# Load Parameter from Local File in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-glue

I am trying to create a glue job from AWS CLI. It works when I use the actual Glue Job name in the `--name` field

```
aws glue create-job \
    --name my-first-glue-job-cli \
    --role arn:aws:iam::***:role/GlueRole \
    --command file://command.json \
    --region us-east-2 \
    --output json \
    --default-arguments file://arguments.json \
    --glue-version 3.0 \
    --profile ***
```

But I want the value attached in the `--name` parameter to be loaded from a file just like `--default-arguments` / `--command`

I understand the latter two options are structure/map type and --name is of string type. I have gone through the [glue documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-job.html)

Also went through the [cli documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html) to load parameters from a file. They only mention json use-cases.

I tried loading the value from a local txt file I created and put the job-name inside that txt file.

```
aws glue create-job \
    --name file://gluejobname.txt \
    --role arn:aws:iam::***:role/GlueRole \
    --command file://command.json \
    --region us-east-2 \
    --output json \
    --default-arguments file://arguments.json \
    --glue-version 3.0 \
    --profile ***
```

Error being displayed is:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateJob operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'my-first-glue-job-cli
' at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF\t]*
```

Comment: If there is a newline character in `gluejobname.txt`, remove it.

Comment: I think cloudformation or terraform could be a better option for this

Comment: @BobHaffner Open to CloudFormation,( I haven't used Terraform ) I am using GitHub Actions to run the above cli commands. I considered using CloudFormation but I have over 100+ Glue jobs in my QA a/c. Would it be a better choice to let GitHub Actions run a workflow where it creates a stack and let CF stack create a glue job? I would also want to update a glue job as well eg update a part of the py script. Can CF take care of that as well? In my case I thought if I have to update a Glue job, I would let GitHub Actions delete the existing job and create a shiny new one. Thoughts?

Comment: @fedonev I would like to accept your answer, is it possible you could post this as your final answer?

Comment: Ok, hmm.  I don't know GH Actions real well, but I know you can pass params (eg job name) to the `aws cloudformation create-stack` cli cmd.  So a CF stack would create a single Glue Job.   Not sure you would gain much over your current strategy other than having the CF template in version control.  Re: Glue Job Scripts, those are stored in S3 in a bucket you specify or by some default.  If you upload new scripts (via GH Actions for example), they will reflect in the next job run or the next time you open the Glue Editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cli will accept a scalar parameter from a file as `file://gluejobname.txt`.  Use unquoted text, no newlines!

Alternatively, pass all params as a single JSON file using the `--cli-input-json` flag.  For example:

```sh
# Generate a template (optional):
aws glue get-job --generate-cli-skeleton > params.json
```

```js
// params.json
{ "JobName": "" }
```

```sh
# pass all params in one file
aws glue get-job --cli-input-json file://params.json
```